How to re-install the latest vite for laravel project (v.11)
I have mistakenly deleted vite and unable to reinstall it.
I tried npm install --save-dev vite @vitejs/plugin-laravel but I am getting npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@vitejs%2fplugin-laravel - Not found.
I could not find any similar question in stackoverlfow.

can you share the package.json?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I wonder if you are looking for laravel-vite-plugin? (also verified in source code: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/11.x/package.json#L12)
